# Why doesn't Harry die when Voldemort uses the killing curse on him?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort, avada-kedavra

Why doesn't Harry die when Voldemort uses the killing curse on him? I'm talking about the second time this happens, when they are in the forbidden forest during the Battle of Hogwarts, not in Godric's Hollow.